# Android Studio: LinkedHashSets did not fix

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am programming a Calculator App. I want to add a course, where you can see your latest results. So I created a new Activity and LinkedHashSets.

I added one String in three LinkedHashSets to have this result:
Date          how Long you worked       Salary.

My Problem now: The LinkedHashSets haven't the right order. They're mixed up. But I need the right order!

When I make it in one LinkedHashSet I have another Problem, the Strings need to be exactly on the left side, mid and right side.

I hope you can help me, I'm out of any ideas ..

Here's my Code:
First Activity (main)

```
            SharedPreferences prefs2;
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefseditor2;

            String datum, gearbeitet, verdienst;

            datum = datumGearbeitet;
            gearbeitet = stundeGesamt + ":" + minute;
            verdienst = gehalt + "";

            prefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("prefsdatei2", MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefseditor2 = prefs2.edit();

           Set<String> test123 = new HashSet<>();
            Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY3", test123));
            Set<String> mySet2 = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY4", test123));
            Set<String> mySet3 = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY5", test123));


                mySet.add(datum);
                mySet2.add(gearbeitet + " h");
                mySet3.add(verdienst);

            prefseditor2.putStringSet("KEY4", mySet2);
            prefseditor2.putStringSet("KEY5", mySet3);
            prefseditor2.putStringSet("KEY3", mySet);
            prefseditor2.commit();

            Intent showMain2 = new Intent(this, MainUebersichtActivity.class);
            startActivity(showMain2);
```

Second Activity:

```
    Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY3", null));

    Set<String> mySet2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY4", null));

    Set<String> mySet3 = new LinkedHashSet<>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY5", null));


    String a = "";
    String b = "";
    String c = "";
    if(mySet != null && mySet2 != null && mySet3 != null) {
        for (String num : mySet) {
            a += num + "\n";
            textv.setText(a);
        }
        for (String num2 : mySet2) {
            b += num2 + "\n";
            textv2.setText(b);
        }
        for (String num3 : mySet3) {
            c += num3 + " €" + "\n";
            textv3.setText(c);
        }
    }

    prefseditor2.putStringSet("mySet", mySet);
    prefseditor2.putStringSet("mySet2", mySet2);
    prefseditor2.putStringSet("mySet3", mySet3);
    prefseditor2.commit();
```

Comment: You're assigning the result of `getStringSet` to your set variables and this is not guaranteed to be a LinkedHashSet.

Comment: How can I fix it? Sorry but i'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY3", null));
```

That creates a new `LinkedHashSet` from the contents of the set that `getStringSet` returns.  If `null` causes a problem pass in `new HashSet<String>()'`.

Comment: I updated both Activites with your option but it ain't work. See this error:  

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.Collection.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:74)

Comment: Sounds like you need to check if the return from `getStringSet` is null or empty before doing that.

Comment: got a performance with:

Set<String> test123 = new HashSet<>();
                Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY3", test123));
                Set<String> mySet2 = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY4", test123));
                Set<String> mySet3 = new HashSet<String>(prefs2.getStringSet("KEY5", test123));

Comment: I have updated my question with the new code. I'm happy to say that I haven't a error anymore. Unfortunately this isn't the solution for the main problem.. it shows the set in wrong order. Thanks that you try to help me! If we can solve this problem my app would be ready to launch

Comment: I'm not sure, I would try stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: I have tried it so often right now, it demotivates me more as you think .. I don't get any errors right now, but I wish I have the right order.

Comment: Oh you know what - I don't think this is going to work at all.  SharedPreferences will not return the keys to you in any particular order.  You can't rely on getting them out in the same order you put them in.  You'll have to come up with some other way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Hell no! I think I can sum up the three Strings into one. It would fix the error, but I have a decrease in my layout. Is it possible to split words in a textView on the left side, mid and on the right side? Because I want the three strings like a list, without differences.

Comment: I don't think so, but you could put three TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: Thats what I have at the moment. Or did you mean sth else? I could put it in one textView, but it won't look really professional, because of the different spaces, in fact of e.g. January and March

Comment: So are you still having a problem?

Comment: Just need to work on a solution for the spaces. Thats all. Hadn't really time to search for one, had some important exams

Comment: Three TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout isn't working?

Comment: I will try it soon. Hadn't enough time. I will post the result ;) thanks for your advice!

Comment: Okay nasch I fixed my code and it works now fine. I've summed up all three Strings into one, so its impossible to change the order. Thanks that you tried to help me!